Crystal Reports - Access All Rows Returned by a Query Instead of One at a Time
I'm using Crystal 2020 and I have two tables, osEntity and osCommunication, that can be joined on osCommunication.fkosEntity=osEntity.PK. osCommunication contains phone numbers for customers in osEntity and each customer can have multiple phone numbers, so naturally this means that some records look like this:
Name            Phone
John Smith      555-555-5555
John Smith      555-555-3333

but I would like it to look like this in my report:
Name            Phone
John Smith      555-555-5555, 555-555-3333

I tried accomplishing this by creating a sub-report and linking osEntity.PK in the outer report to osCommunication.fkosEntity in the sub-report and then creating a formula that loops through osCommunication.information, the field that contains the phone numbers, to concatenate them like so,
stringvar array numbers := {osCommunication.Information};
numbervar cnt := count(numbers);
stringvar out := "";
numbervar i;

for i := 1 to cnt - 1 step 1 do (
    out := out + numbers[i] + ", ";
);
out := out + numbers[cnt];
out

The problem is that Crystal is only giving me access to one row at a time, so this formula produces something more like 5, 5, 5, -, 5, 5, 5, -, 5, 5, 5, 5 rather than 555-555-5555, 555-555-3333. Is there a way that I can get access to all rows returned by the query to osCommunication at once rather than one row at a time? I've done something like this with parameters from user input before but I'm struggling to do the same with the result of a query. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.
UPDATE: I was able to work out the following solution thanks to @MilletSoftware
Admittedly, I don't fully understand why, but I wasn't able to get the list of concatenated phone numbers to print in the group footer of each group until I changed all of my global variables to shared variables. I also ended up using a string array to make filtering out duplicates a little easier. None the less, I'll include my completed solution here for the sake of those who may be looking to do something similar.
Group Header Section:
Shared StringVar Array Phones; //Array containing all phone numbers related to the current group.
Redim Phones[1]; //Reset the Array at the start of each group.
Shared NumberVar reCount; //Current record count for the current group.
Shared StringVar currentEntity; //The entity ID of the current group.

//Check if starting a new group. If so, update the current group's EntityID and resent the record count.
If currentEntity = "" or currentEntity <> {osEntity.EntityID} Then
(
    currentEntity := {osEntity.EntityID};
    reCount := 1
);

Details Section:
Shared StringVar Array Phones;
Shared NumberVar reCount;

//Only add phone number to array if it is unique
If Not({osCommunication.Information} In Phones) Then
(
    ReDim Preserve Phones[reCount];
    Phones[reCount] := {osCommunication.Information};
    reCount := reCount + 1;
);

Group Footer Section:
Shared StringVar Array Phones;

//Join all phone numbers in the array into a comma separated list
Join(Phones,', ');


Group by Customer.
In the Group Header, use a formula to reset a global string variable.
Global Stringvar Phones := "";

In the detail section, concatenate the phone number to the global variable:
Global StringVar Phones := Phones + {Customer.Phone} + ", " ;

In the Group Footer, use a formula to get rid of the last comma, and display the phone numbers:
Global StringVar Phones;
IF Len(Phones) > 2 Then Phones := LEFT(Phones, Len(Phones) - 2);
Phones;


Thank you for your very elegant solution. I didn't think to use groups in that way but it makes sense that it should be possible to accumulate values as Crystal iterates over them. That being said, I might be doing something a little off because it doesn't quite seem to work as expected. When I implement the solution as described, all of my phone fields printed blank. I tried adding WhileReadingRecords to start of the third formula, which caused it to print the accumulated phone numbers but also to accumulate phone numbers across groups. I can't seem to get it to print just one group and reset

I just realized I didn't @ you on my previous comment. Once again, if nothing else, I'd like to say thank you for your advice. If I can trouble you just a little further though, would you be able to provide some insight into where I'm failing, as I noted in my previous comment? It seems like the solution should be working because if I double-click the blank fields, I can see where the phone numbers are accumulating with each record in the details section but I can't seem to get them to print in the footer section. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.
